# creating a hyperlink inside a table using php/mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to create a hyperlink using php. the hyper link is in a table..

this is my code:

```
 echo"<tr><td>"<a href='".$row['hyperPath'] . ">click here</a></td></tr>";
```

I am getting an error

How can i fix this?

Comment: What error? Where is $row defined? after about 20 questions in this site, I'd expect you to learn how to ask.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
echo"<tr><td><a href='".$row['hyperPath'] . "'>click here</a></td></tr>";
```

You had an extra " after your  tag. If you really want the " to be displayed you need to escape it first with \ like this:

```
echo"<tr><td>\"<a href='".$row['hyperPath'] . "'>click here</a></td></tr>";
```

You were also missing the closing quote for your href attribute (added before >click here)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='".$row['hyperPath']."'>click here</a></td></tr>";
```